# Extend continously an integral function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, improper-integrals, integral-domain

If I have an integral function, for instance $F(x)=\int_1^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{3-t}}\,dt$, surely the domain of the integrand is $(-\infty, 3)$ and then can I say that since $\lim_{x\to 3^-}F(x)=\int_1^{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3-t}}\,dt$ converges I can continuously extend the integral function in $x=3$ imposing that $F(3)=\lim_{x\to 3^-}F(x)\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\int_1^xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is at best ambiguous at worst meaningless.

Comment: @user10354138 anyway do you think what I have affirmed is correct?

Comment: @user10354138 can you help me? I would like to have a confirmation of my idea

Comment: Yes, that's right (strictly speaking, $F$ is continuous from the left at $3$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks!